# Use DOM to add the attribute between opening and closing tags instead of one tag

Tags: java, xml, dom

So I am using the DOM parser in JAVA to create an XML file.
When I want to add a child element it ends up looking like this:

```
<childElement attribute1="attributeValue" attribute2="attributeValue"/>
```

However I would rather that my XML look like this (though obviously DOM won't make these indentations and seperate lines):

```
<childElement>
    <attribute1>attributeValue</attribute1>
    <attribute2>attributeValue</attribute2>
</childElement>
```

Existing Code that was outputed (what i don't want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Dennis>
        <Hair Colour="Brown"/>
    </Dennis>
    <!--This is a comment :)-->
```

What I want it to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Dennis>
        <Hair>
            <Colour>Brown</colour>
        </Hair>
    </Dennis>
    <!--This is a comment :)-->
```

*Note: I understand if java won't be able to make all these indentations and what not. What I DO want it to do is to use the `"<open tag>value<close tag>"` format.

Comment: It will be easier for us to explain the change if you post the code you have that's creating xml in the format you don't like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an element named `attribute1` to the element `childElement`.

DOM itself is memory based but you can serialize it to xml and most libraries have pretty printers, that do the indentation.

**Further Reading**

- http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html

The section *Write document to file* shows how to format the output with this library.

Comment: Perfect but for the attribute1, unlike the childElement, you have to use "Element.createTextNode" instead of "Element.createElement"

Comment: Not exactly. Use Document#createElement to create a `Hair` element and add it to `Dennis`. Then use Document#createTextNode to create the text node `Brown` and add it to `Hair`.